# Как правильно закрывать Activity

Tags: android

Возможно глупый вопрос, но как правильно закрывать Activity:

до запуска нового активити

```
finish();
startActivity...;
```

или после

```
startActivity...
finish();
```

Comment: вообще ее специально закрывать вовсе не надо, но если в этом есть какая то крайняя необходимость, то после старта новой

Comment: @pavlofff а если мне нужно выйти из приложения?Как иначе организовать выход?Ибо у меня бывают какие-то баги,что мол нажимаю выход,активити заново перезагружается,хотя в OnBack.. написано finish(), после второго нажатия,всё закрывается

Answer (score 6):

Вообще то без разницы. Все равно эти методы не прямого (немедленного действия), а будут выполняться в реальности только после того как они попадут в очередь обработки сообщений *MessageQueue*, который исполняется в UI Thread - в т.н. `MainLooper` (`Looper.getMainLooper()`)

Фактически вызов и `finish()` и `startActivity()`, равно как вообще любые действия с оконной системой а ля `setText()` будут транслированы в сообщения, которые будет обрабатывать `Looper` - примерно как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С этой точки зрения - очередность не играет роли.

Comment: А разве очередь не подразумевает, что действия будут выполнены в том порядке, в котором они в неё попали (были вызваны в коде)?

Comment: Совершенно верно, очередь подразумевает, что они будут выполняться именно так, но это никак не означает, что на момент выполнения `startActivity()` будет уничтожен `Activity`, на который перед этим и был вызван `finish()`. То есть если бы методы были *прямого* действия, то такое поведение привело бы к краху, грубо говоря, не получилось бы сначала уничтожить, а потом из уничтоженного экземпляра что-то вызвать... Как то так.